# Onclick not triggered on objects

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a table with X rows in it. I have the following HTML code:

```
<tr id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick('1')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row2' onClick="FormTRClick('2')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row3' onClick="FormTRClick('3')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row4' onClick="FormTRClick('4')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
```

Now, when you click on the hyperlink 'Bla' you will **also** activate the OnClick event. Is there a way to only trigger the OnClick event when you **don't** click on an object (like button, image, href) but only on the table row itself?

My FormTRClick() function looks as follow:

```
function FormTRClick(ctrl) {
   if (document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked == true) {
    document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = false;
   } else {
    document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = true;
   }
}
```

I know I could also use the inverse `document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = !document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked` but that's not the point, I have extra code in there.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to attach an event listener to those clicks, and stop the propogation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation

---

Alternatively, you can check for the target element:

HTML:

```
<tr id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '1')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row2' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '2')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row3' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '3')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
<tr id='row4' onClick="FormTRClick(event, '4')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
```

Javascript:

```
function FormTRClick(event, ctrl) {
    if (event.target.tagName != 'A' && document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked == true) {
        document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have changed the part into if the event.target.tagName is TD though. Works the best!

Comment: I've just found that it doesn't work in IE, I get the following error:
`'target.tagName' is null or not an object`. I've tried using nodeName isntead of tagName but to no avail.

Comment: The problem is not with `tagName`. It's that IE doesn't do `target`. Use `event.srcElement` for IE. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534638(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Since the links are part of the table row, they will always trigger the onclick for the table row when you click them.

There is a simple workaround, however...

```
<tr id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick('1');"><td><a href='#' onmouseover="linkOver();" onmouseout="linkOut();">Bla</a></td></tr>
```

...and some javascript...

```
var linkIsOver = false;

function FormTRClick(ctrl) {
  if (!linkIsOver) {
    if (document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById('chk' + ctrl).checked = true;
    }
  }
}

function linkOver () {
  linkIsOver = true;
}
function linkOut () {
  linkIsOver = false;
}
```

Comment: This solution will work, but it's not an elegant way. I accepted Joseph's answer since his is clean.

Answer (score 0):

So do it like that. In HTML:

```
<tr id='row1' onClick="FormTRClick(this, '1')"><td><a href='#'>Bla</a></td></tr>
```

In JS:

```
function FormTRClick(elem, ctrl) {
    if (elem.tagName != 'TR') return;
    //do what you need
}
```

**UPDATED WITH UPPER-CASE TAG NAME**

Comment: Clicking the link will still trigger the event and pass the table row, since the link is part of the table row...

Comment: Yes, Dave is right. It's still activating the onClick event unfortunately.